# Benchmarking FULLTEXT performance - how to

Tags: php, mysql, apache, sphinx, full-text-search

**Background**

I need to implement `FULLTEXT` search on a `MySQL` server database (in the size range of 10k-200k records).

As of now, database search is based on naive implementation (`LIKE` queries), which is obviously inefficient, not to mention unconfigurable etc.

Two alternatives are considered:

1. Enabling `MySQL`'s native FULLTEXT (requires adding one or more `MyISAM` tables - the entire database is `InnoDB` right now);
2. Installing [`Sphinx`](http://sphinxsearch.com/).

(We use PHP 5.2 and upgrading is not an option, so InnoDB FULLTEXT is out of question here.)

**The problem**

There are performance considerations. It is understandable that implementing `FULLTEXT` either way will eat more disk space as well as put more burden on the CPU.

The goal is to find out, by how much. Both solutions are to be benchmarked against eachother (as well as the status quo of course). I need to set up and perform these tests.

The way I would go about it is:

1. Fill up a database with real data (say 100k rows);
2. Measure the time required to build an index;
3. Simulate the need of reindexing by inserting / updating a few thousands rows - again, profiling the time required as well as CPU and RAM usage;
4. Testing query speed with a set of short and long phrases, in both boolean and natural language mode.

Fairly simple so far, but any advice would be much appreciated, since I am more of a desktop / client app dev and I'm way out of my comfort zone.

**Questions**

1. What am I missing? Is this test scenario likely to yield meaningful results?
2. What is the right way to monitor server CPU and RAM usage if not a cron script?

I'm aware it is a bit of an open question, I hope it won't get closed though.

Comment: even for 200k records it's no difference between sphinx and myisam search. But for me myisam Percona Server is faster with fulltext + indexes

Comment: LIKE+index is enough if you dont use both side search (%ddd%)

Comment: @DenisErmolin - we do, however. Plus we really are after better accuracy ("did you mean..." functionality and such)

Comment: @KonradMorawski Sorry for the off topic; how is the job market in Poland? Could we possibly take this discussion over e-mail?

Comment: @njk yes no problem, feel free to contact me at morawski dot uk at gmail dot com

Answer (score 3):

That scenario looks fine, I would just suggest implementing delta indexes in sphinx (indexing only changes since last index).

On monitoring you can setup cacti or munin tools but if you are going to use them only for this tests maybe dstat is more then enough.